# How to add timestamp directly to the cell that I just filled/edited in google sheet

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets-api

I would like to ask that is it possible to add the timestamp directly to all the cells that I just filled/edited in google sheet. For example, I just added some contents to the cell A1, like: Hello, then what I expect displaying in the cell A1 is something like: Hello - 20.05.2016 00:50.

Are there having some ideas? :D

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is through using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), rather than the Sheets API.  Create a script attached to the spreadsheet, and define an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) method. This method fires whenever cells in the sheet are edited.  The method can get the edited value from the trigger event, create and append a timestamp, and then fill the cell with the timestamp value.

Using the Sheets API instead would likely require some kind of polling of the sheet, looking for changes and taking action when they are found. It is possible, but is likely more complex and less efficient than the Apps Script solution.